# single page application angular 4

Tags: angular, single-page-application, github-pages

I want to deploy a single page application in angular 4 on github using command line.

But When I open the link for the site this is displayed :
[image: site being displayed as]

Whereas it should display something like this:

[image: actual site]

[Link to my repository](https://github.com/moondustkj/sample)

[Link to the site hosted on github](https://moondustkj.github.io/sample/)

can anyone help me to resolve this problem ?

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my assumptions are correct you are trying to deploy your Angular app to Github pages. This can be done by following these steps:

#### 1. install the angular-cli-ghpages

`npm install -g angular-cli-ghpages`

#### 2. Use the Angular CLI to build the project

`ng build --prod --base-href https://<GITHUB_USER_NAME>.github.io/<REPO_NAME>/`

#### 3. Publish your application to Github pages

`angular-cli-ghpages`

If everything went well you should now be able to see your Angular app at `https://<GITHUB_USERNAME>.github.io/<REPO_NAME>/`

#### Additional note for CLI version 6+

> With Angular CLI 6 the build artifacts will be put in a subfolder under dist. Please take a look at the dist folder to see whether there is a subfolder with your project's name or not. If yes, you need to specify the deploy directory manually then when using this tool: `npx ngh --dir=dist/[PROJECTNAME]` I most cases, the `[PROJECTNAME]` can be found in the `angular.json` file at `defaultProject`.

[Source](https://github.com/angular-schule/angular-cli-ghpages/)

Comment: I deployed the site using this method but now a 404 error is displayed -"The site configured at this address does not contain the requested file." I guess in index.html there is error the base href I have written is :<base href="https://moondustkj.github.io/sample/"> what changes should I make ?

Comment: Apparently an extra step might be needed when you are using Angular CLI version 6 or higher. I've updated my answer with this additional step.

Answer (score 0):

You must build your angular for deployment using either

1. `ng build` if you just want to share your progress and ideas internally with managers, teammates, and other stakeholders, this will leave your codes as it is.
2. `ng build --prod` this will optimize and minimize your code.

You would see the output in `dist/` folder

Comment: okay I'll try to use this method and see if it helps me. Thanks for answering.